# How to record a Microsoft Teams meeting to One Drive or Sharepoint?

Tags: google-chrome, cloud, microsoft, voip, microsoft-teams

On Microsoft Teams, the button to record audio is grayed out:

[image]

The Microsoft [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/record-a-meeting-in-teams-34dfbe7f-b07d-4a27-b4c6-de62f1348c24) makes mention of the fact that, beginning Aug 2021, there are some changes, so that recordings are put directly to `SharePoint` or `One Drive`:

> As of August 2021, Teams meeting recordings will no longer be saved to
> Microsoft Stream. Moving forward, all meeting recordings will be saved
> to OneDrive and SharePoint. Some organizations are already choosing to
> make this change. For those users, migration to OneDrive and
> SharePoint began in October 2020.

How is this accomplished from Ubuntu?

I'm running 21.04.